# instanceof returns Error for my custom exception class

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have the following code to throw and catch a custom exception:

```
class CreateValidationError extends Error {
    constructor(message?: string) {
        super(message);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype); // restore prototype chain
        this.name = CreateValidationError.name; // stack traces display correctly now 
    }
}

function doSomething() {
    throw new CreateValidationError('abc')
}

function funcOne() {
    try {
        doSomething()
    }
    catch(e) {
        if (e instanceof Error) { console.log('its an error') }// this prints correctly 

        if (e instanceof CreateValidationError) { console.log('its a CreateValidation error') } // this does not print 
    }
}
```

The issue is that `instanceof` only detects the base class and not the derived class.

Am I doing something wrong in defining the custom exception?

Or are there any known gotchas related to TypeScript or Webpack that would cause the class hierarchy to be lost during the build?

Comment: It *may* be webpack, but I cannot reproduce your problem in either my browser console or the typescript playground. `console.log(e instanceof CreateValidationError);` prints `true` in both places. Please post your webpack config.

Comment: you have a extra colon after `if (e instanceof CreateValidationError)`

Comment: Fixed the typo. @jared Thanks, I've got other use cases which aren't exception handling in the same code base where it works fine, so it's subtle. I'll pull the webpack config file shortly.